# How to display a foreign key's true value in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I will start off by saying that I'm pretty new to using the php language and really only started learning it via this little project to create a small movie database.

Some background before we get to the php code itself -- the database is called movie_library and it contains 3 tables called movies, movie_format, and movie_genre. Movies has the fields id, title, genre, and format (i.e. DVD/Blu-ray). The purpose of the movie_format and movie_genre tables is to make entry easier and thus, I've set these tables up to be foreign keys linking to their respective fields.

Below is the relevant code snippet. The $conn variable is just the database connection code.

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM movies") or die("Bad Query: $sql");
echo"<table border='2'>";
echo"<tr><td>ID</td><td>Title</td><td>Genre</td><td>Format</td></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo"<tr><td>{$row['id']}</td><td>{$row['title']}</td><td>{$row['genre']}</td><td>{$row['format']}</td></tr>";
}
```

This code by itself technically works correctly, but the issue that I have is since the 2 tables I mentioned use foreign keys the table ends up looking like this:

[image]

Obviously the genre and format fields are supposed to be words and not numbers, so here inlies my issue. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
After changing the code to

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM movies 
LEFT JOIN movie_format ON movies.format = movie_format.id 
LEFT JOIN movie_genre ON movies.genre = movie_genre.id")
```

which gave me this output:

[image]

For whatever reason the ID field and the Genre Fields are linked, but the code is pretty much exactly the same as the code which works for Format.

Comment: Look into JOINs,basically your query should be something like `SELECT * FROM movies LEFT JOIN movie_format ON movies.id = movie_format.movie_id LEFT JOIN movie_genre ON..`

Comment: It looks like you are outputting the foreign key in the `movies` table (`movies.genre`) rather than the column in table `movie_genre` that describes the genre. It's hard to say because you are outputting `$row['genre']` and you haven't showed the names of the columns in all the tables but that is certainly the name of the foreign key in table `movies`.  Also, any reason why you are using a left join rather than an inner join?